# How to make boxes go over the div?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a web page and I've got 3 columns in a div row and I want them to go over the div.
What do I need to do to make it like that?

I've tried using flex box, z index positioning etc but it didn't work. Here is what I want it to look like:

[image]

and this is what it looks like right now:

[image]

Here is the code that I've got so far:

```css
.column1 {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5e4e2;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 130px;
  margin-right: 160px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px #5E5E5E;
}

.column2 {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #a9a9a9;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 160px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px #5E5E5E;
}

.column3 {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 130px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px #5E5E5E;
}
```

```html
<div style="float:left;width:100%;background-color: #c5c5c5;margin-top:100px;padding-top:100px;">
  <h3 style="text-align: center;font-size:30pt">Are thinking all the time about...</h3>
  <h3 style="text-align: center;padding-bottom: 100px;font-size:30pt">(how to solve main problem), then these 3 ideas for you</h3>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column1"><img style="padding-bottom:20px" src="images/circle.png">
      <h3 style="padding-bottom:20px;font-size:16pt">Method 1</h3>
      <p style="font-size: 14pt;">Visual icon above and subtext comes here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column2"><img style="padding-bottom:20px" src="images/circle.png">
      <h3 style="padding-bottom:20px;font-size:16pt">Method 2</h3>
      <p style="font-size: 14pt;">Visual icon above and subtext comes here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column3"><img style="padding-bottom:20px" src="images/circle.png">
      <h3 style="padding-bottom:20px;font-size:16pt">Method 3</h3>
      <p style="font-size: 14pt;">Visual icon above and subtext comes here</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have 3 sets of CSS? Have ONE set of CSS for class="column" and then have the difference in #column1, #column2 etc: `#column1 {
  background-color: #e5e4e2;
}

#column2 {
  background-color: #a9a9a9;
}

#column3 {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #fff;
}`

Comment: use absolute positioning

Comment: Btw you can use `flexbox` for making your code easier. Instead of writing `column1`, `column2`... you could just add a parent-element with `flex` `flex-wrap`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Just changing the height of the container should be what you're looking for. See a demo here - https://codepen.io/tomdringer/pen/XWgWxKr

Can you not just give the grey background a specific height and then `overflow: visible`? Also with the CSS, don't repeat yourself. Make your css like this:

```
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 100px 20px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 130px;
  margin-right: 160px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px #5E5E5E;
}

.column1{
  background-color: #e5e4e2;
}

.column2{
  background-color: #a9a9a9;
}

.column3{
  background-color: #000000;
}
```